# Autosys Box run configuration

Tags: unix, autosys

I have an Autosys box and there is a couple of jobs inside it.
For example, MY_BOX is the name of the box and it has the jobs JOB_1 and JOB_2.

I would like to configure the box in such a way that it runs continuously. (i.e.) as soon as the JOB_2 completes (success or failure), MY_BOX should start running again. Could you please tell me how to configure this?

I tried setting the "run condition" for MY_BOX as SUCCESS(JOB_2), however, the Box does not start after the completeion of JOB_2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how to make MY_BOX run immediately after the success of JOB_2, but you could set the interval on which MY_BOX runs to just about (or a little bit more) than the average run of MY_BOX.

I.E. - if MY_BOX runs for about 10 minutes, have MY_BOX run every ten/eleven minutes. Or try setting it's condition to the SUCCESS(MY_BOX).

Answer (score 0):

You can also give the condition as done(MY_BOX) to the MY_BOX as you want the MY_BOX to run immediately irrespective of the success or failure of JOB_2.

If the JOB_2 fails then the MY_BOX also fails then the condition success(MY_BOX) will not make the MY_BOX to run. So if you give the condition as done(MY_BOX),irrespective of the success or failure of MY_BOX, the MY_BOX will start running immediately.